# MapFileMemory(dwAllocSize: DWord); 'Hook DLL', 'Could not map file'

Tags: delphi, winapi, 64-bit

While porting my old 32 bit code to 64 bit, I am getting

'Hook DLL', 'Could not map file'

## What am I doing wrong?

```
var
  hObjHandle: THandle; //Variable for the file mapping object
  lpHookRec: PHookRec; //Pointer to our hook record

procedure MapFileMemory(dwAllocSize: DWord);
begin //MapFileMemory
  //Create a process wide memory mapped variable
  hObjHandle := CreateFileMapping($FFFFFFFF, nil, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, dwAllocSize, 'HookRecMemBlock');
  if (hObjHandle = 0) then
    begin
      MessageBox(0, 'Hook DLL', 'Could not create file map object', mb_Ok);
      exit
    end;// (hObjHandle = 0)

  //Get a pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable
  lpHookRec := MapViewOfFile(hObjHandle, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, dwAllocSize);
  if (lpHookRec = nil) then
    begin
      CloseHandle(hObjHandle);
      MessageBox(0, 'Hook DLL', 'Could not map file', mb_Ok);
      exit
    end //lpHookRec = Nil)
end; //MapFileMemory

procedure UnMapFileMemory;
begin //UnMapFileMemory
  //Delete our process wide memory mapped variable
  if (lpHookRec <> nil) then
    begin
      UnMapViewOfFile(lpHookRec);
      lpHookRec := nil
    end; // (lpHookRec <> Nil)
  if (hObjHandle > 0) then
    begin
      CloseHandle(hObjHandle);
      hObjHandle := 0
    end //(hObjHandle > 0)
end; // UnMapFileMemory


procedure DllEntryPoint(dwReason: DWord);
begin { DllEntryPoint }
  case dwReason of
    Dll_Process_Attach:
      begin
        {if we are getting mapped into a process, then get}
        {a pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable}
        hObjHandle := 0;
        lpHookRec := nil;
        MapFileMemory(sizeof(lpHookRec^))
      end;
    Dll_Process_Detach:
      begin
        {if we are getting unmapped from a process then, remove}
        {the pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable}
        UnMapFileMemory
      end;
  end { case dwReason }
end; { DllEntryPoint }
```

Comment: This is code from internet.

Comment: Read the docs. I bet that on 64 bit the first arg to CreateFileMapping is not $ffffffff. Pass INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. Try to understand your code rather run copying it blindly

Comment: Why you want change your project to 64 bits? a 32 bits program also is supported by x64 processors. :-)

Comment: @Franciscocamilo, because he wants to map files > 2GB.

Comment: @Franciscocamilo not all 64bit systems can run 32bit programs, actually. The Wow64 emulator is required to run 32bit apps, and on some 64bit versions of Windows that component is *optional* and may not be installed.

Comment: Thanks @David, Francisco, Johan, Remy, You guys rock

Comment: Can you all please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38330335/how-to-post-extended-ascii-chars-0x80-to-0xff-using-postmessage-in-delphi

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the relevant changes to allow for the fact that you're running on 64 bit.

Oh and read up on Raymond Chen's [essential writings on DllMain](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873), and [the followup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040128-00/?p=40853).
You really should not be doing the mapping of the memory mapped file in `DllMain`.
Instead you should wait until your dll client starts calling any of the work routines in your dll and only then do the mapping.

On top of that it's always a good idea to [include the actual error](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.SysErrorMessage) if you're debugging.

```
var
  hObjHandle: THandle; //Variable for the file mapping object
  lpHookRec: PHookRec; //Pointer to our hook record

procedure MapFileMemory(dwAllocSize: NativeUInt);
begin
  if Assigned(lpHookRec) then exit;
  hObjHandle := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, dwAllocSize, 'HookRecMemBlock');
  if (hObjHandle = 0) then begin
    MessageBox(0, 'Hook DLL', 'Could not create file map object '#10#13+
               SysErrorMessage(GetLastError), mb_Ok);
    exit;
  end;

  //Get a pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable
  lpHookRec := MapViewOfFile(hObjHandle, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, dwAllocSize);
  if (lpHookRec = nil) then begin
    CloseHandle(hObjHandle);
    MessageBox(0, 'Hook DLL', 'Could not map file '#10#13+
               SysErrorMessage(GetLastError), mb_Ok);
    exit;
  end; 
end;

procedure UnMapFileMemory;
begin 
  //Delete our process wide memory mapped variable
  if Assigned(lpHookRec) then begin
    UnMapViewOfFile(lpHookRec);
    lpHookRec := nil;
  end; 
  if (hObjHandle <> 0) then begin
    CloseHandle(hObjHandle);
    hObjHandle := 0;
  end; 
end;

var
  CS: TRTLCriticalSection;    

procedure DllEntryPoint(dwReason: DWord);
begin { DllEntryPoint }
  case dwReason of
    Dll_Process_Attach: begin
      {if we are getting mapped into a process, then get}
      {a pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable}
      hObjHandle := 0;
      lpHookRec := nil;
      //do not call MapMemFile here, do it when your work-routine is called for the first time.
    end;
    Dll_Process_Detach: begin
      {if we are getting unmapped from a process then, remove}
      {the pointer to our process wide memory mapped variable}
      EnterCriticalSection(CS);
        if Assigned(lpHookRec) then UnMapFileMemory;
      LeaveCriticalSection(CS);
    end;
  end; { case dwReason }
end; { DllEntryPoint }
```

Comment: Except for the calls to `MessageBox`, everything else was safe to do from `DllMain`. This is explicitly explained under [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx).

Comment: Wow, that worked

However, 
1) I Could not add SysErrorMessage(GetLastError) function to know the actual error (may be, I need to include some unit, please advise)
2) If I don't include the MapFileMemory(sizeof(lpHookRec^)) in DllMain, how do I determine the "First Use" and run that function?