# How to post Extended ASCII chars (0x80 to 0xFF) using PostMessage in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-events, postmessage, win64, extended-ascii

I am writing a Keyboard Mapper Application in which I need to send Extended ASCII chars (0x80 to 0xFF) to Current Window. I have tried everything like  below

```
function ConstructLParam(vKey: Word): LongInt; // Cardinal;
begin { ConstructLParam }
  if vKey > $FF then
    Result := LongInt(MapVirtualKeyW(vKey, 0) and $00000FFF or $F000) shl 16 or 1
  else
    Result := LongInt(MapVirtualKey(vKey, 0) and $000000FF or $FF00) shl 16 or 1;
end; { ConstructLParam }

procedure PostCharacter(TargetWinHandle: Hwnd; UniCodeValue: Word; IME_MSG, WideFunction, SimulateKey, SendMSG: Boolean);
begin { PostCharacter }
  if SendMSG then  // SendMSG Fn
    if IME_MSG then //  IME Msg
      if WideFunction then //  Wide Fn
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          SendMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end
      else                 //  Not Wide Fn
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          SendMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end
    else            //  Not IME Msg
      if WideFunction then //  Wide Fn
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          SendMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end
      else                 //  Not Wide Fn
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          SendMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            SendMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end
  else             // Not SendMSG Fn
    if IME_MSG then //  IME Msg
      if WideFunction then //  Wide Fn
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          PostMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end
      else                 //  Not Wide Fn
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          PostMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_IME_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end
    else            //  Not IME Msg
      if WideFunction then //  Wide Fn
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          PostMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessageW(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end
      else
        begin
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          PostMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_CHAR, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue));
          if SimulateKey then
            PostMessage(TargetWinHandle, WM_KEYUP, MakeWParam(UniCodeValue, 0), (ConstructLParam(UniCodeValue) or $C0000000));
        end;

end; { PostCharacter }
```

But none of this works in Win64 (it use to work fine under Win32) :(

Can anybody please help, how to post Extended ASCII chars (0x80 to 0xFF) ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Windows does not use extended ASCII. It uses Unicode and has an ANSI layer for back compat. Stop using ANSI. It's 2016. Use Unicode. And why are you faking input this way. The correct way is with `SendInput`. And in any case, isn't it better to use automation? And if you are struggling with this code and must do it that way, why not consider doing some debugging? Why do programmers today not know how to debug? How can anybody be a programmer without learning to debug. We should take your internet away from you for a month and force you to learn how to debug!!

Comment: @David, 

The application works fine for Unicode (and upto 0x7F too) The issue is only with 0x80 to 0xFF

I need to do this, since there is a lot of data been created using old vernacular fonts

Comment: See [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513) and [Simulating input via WM_CHAR messages may fake out the recipient but it won't fake out the input system](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110728-00/?p=10033/)

Comment: That being said, `LPARAM` is 64 bits in Win64, not 32bit like your cide assumes, so you should be using `LPARAM` instead of `LongInt` in `ConstructLParam()`, or use `MAKELPARAM()` instead of manual bit shifting.

Comment: Thanks, actually I need the code to work in Win32 as well as Win64